# how to create the surface plot with unequal vector size

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
clc
clear all
n1=rand(1,10);
n2=rand(1,10);
n3=rand(1,10);
n4=rand(1,10);
m1=rand(1,10);
m2=rand(1,10);
m3=rand(1,10);
m4=rand(1,10);
n=[n1;n2;n3;n4];
m=[m1;m2;m3;m4];
z=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4];
```

I want to create a surface plot using above data.for given z=0.1 plot(n1,m1), for z=0.2 plot(n2,m2)....how to combine all this to get a surface plot?

Comment: what kind of surface are you expecting to get from this data?

Comment: some irregular surface. but my actual code will give some sensible surface plot

Comment: @vijay you need to show us what you mean, it is unclear now

Comment: wait, do you mean `rand(1)*10` ????

Comment: No n1 is a vector of dimension 1*10. using n1,n2,n3,n4 and using m1,m2,m3,m4 and  z   can we able to plot the surface

Answer (score 0):

Mathwork's answer on [how to plot scattered](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-scattered-data.html) data should give you the best start.

I assume that your minimal example is not correct regarding `z`, because all data has to have the same dimension.
Fixing this, interpolation is one answer to your approach.
Following the mentioned link, it should look like this:

```
n = rand(4,10);
m = rand(4,10);
z=repmat([0.1 : 0.1 : 0.4]',1,size(n,2));
resolution = 0.01;
[xi,yi] = meshgrid(min(n):resolution:max(n), min(m):resolution:max(m));
zi = griddata(n,m,z,xi,yi);
surf(xi,yi,zi);
```